# The type Enum is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <RestClient.RequestMethod>

Tags: java, android, enums

```
The type Enum is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <RestClient.RequestMethod>
```

I've this error in the following code ..

```
package ayanoo.utility;

    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
    import java.net.URL;
    import java.util.Vector;

    import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
    import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
    import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
    import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
    import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
    import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
    import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
    import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest;
    import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
    import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
    import org.apache.http.protocol.HTTP;

    import android.util.Log;

    public class  RestClient {

     public enum RequestMethod
     {
     GET,
     POST
     }

        private Vector <NameValuePair> params;

        private String url;

        private int responseCode;
        private String message;

        private String response;

        public String getResponse() {
            return response;
        }

        public String getErrorMessage() {
            return message;
        }

        public int getResponseCode() {
            return responseCode;
        }

        public RestClient(String url)
        {
            this.url = url;
            params = new Vector<NameValuePair>();
        }

        public void AddParam(String name, String value)
        {
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(name, value));
        }

        public void Execute(RequestMethod method) throws IOException
        {
            switch(method) {
                case GET:
                {
                    //add parameters
                    String combinedParams = "";
                    if(!params.isEmpty()){
                        combinedParams += "/";
                        for(NameValuePair p : params)
                        {
                            //String paramString = p.getName() + "=" + p.getValue();
                         String paramString = p.getValue();
                            if(combinedParams.length() > 1)
                            {
                                combinedParams  +=  "&" + paramString;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                combinedParams += paramString;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    Log.d("URL See:",url + combinedParams);
                    URL urlObject = new URL(url + combinedParams);
                    //URL urlObject = new URL("http://www.aydeena.com/Services/Search.svc/JSON/SearchByText/1");

                    executeRequest(urlObject);
                    break;
                }
                case POST:
                {
                    HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);

                    //add headers

                    if(!params.isEmpty()){
                        request.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, HTTP.UTF_8));
                    }

                    executeRequest(request, url);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        private void executeRequest(URL urlObject) throws IOException{
         HttpURLConnection con = null;
         con = (HttpURLConnection) urlObject.openConnection();
            con.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
            con.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
            con.setRequestMethod("GET");
            //con.addRequestProperty("Referer",
              //    "http://www.pragprog.com/titles/eband/hello-android");
            con.setDoInput(true);

            // Start the query
            con.connect();
            response = convertStreamToString(con.getInputStream());
            Log.d("Response:", response);
        }

        private void executeRequest(HttpUriRequest request, String url)
        {
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            Log.d("Test URL:", url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse;

            try {
                httpResponse = client.execute(request);
                responseCode = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
                message = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase();

                HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();

                if (entity != null) {

                    InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
                    response = convertStreamToString(instream);

                    // Closing the input stream will trigger connection release
                    instream.close();
                }

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e)  {
                client.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                client.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        private static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            String line = null;
            try {
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    is.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return sb.toString();
        }
    }
```

what's the problem ??? !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure the Java compiler is set to 1.5 (default for android) or better? If you are using Eclipse you can see that from the preferences.

Comment: That is strange. What platform are you using? Make a simple experiment by commenting out the enum and using a Java 1.5 feature (a varagrs method for example: private myMethod(String... args).

Comment: no no, it's solved .. do you know how ?? I've run another project .. and the error was solved

Comment: I can only explain the error, if you were using a Java 1.4 compiler.

Comment: Maybe you could post the solution as an answer, and accept it.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem, and it turned out that it was because the standard lib was not in the eclipse class path for the project. Just go into **Build Path -> Add Libraries** and add the JRE System Library

Comment: Thanks - this turned out to be my issue too. The JRE System Library was defined, but pointing to a invalid path.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

I only had one error in my project which was the "is not generic one'.

After I commented out the Enum code I found a lot more errors.

There seemed to be some kind of hold-up. Only after fixing the other errors and then removing the comments did it work.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I also saw this error message for a project that was previously working fine.

I checked the compiler version (I am using 1.6) as well as the system library (it is already being used) to no avail.

Finally I just closed the project and then re-opened it, and then the problem went away.  Sounds like an Eclipse bug to me.